# Got Http response code 500 when accessing https://api-3t.sandbox.paypal.com/2.0

Tags: php, soap, paypal

When trying to submit the form I get this issue all the time.

Type :- PPConnectionException
Message :- Got Http response code 500 when accessing https://api-3t.sandbox.paypal.com/2.0.
From the SOAP "faultstring" node:
`SOAP-ENV:ClientData type '' mismatch in element 'ebl:PaymentAction'`

And the entire log file for the transaction with FINE.
    `PPHttpConnection: Adding header X-PAYPAL-REQUEST-DATA-FORMAT: SOAP
PPHttpConnection: Adding header X-PAYPAL-RESPONSE-DATA-FORMAT: SOAP
PPHttpConnection: Adding header X-PAYPAL-DEVICE-IPADDRESS: 127.0.0.1
PPHttpConnection: Adding header X-PAYPAL-REQUEST-SOURCE: merchant-php-sdk-3.7.112
PPHttpConnection: Adding header User-Agent: PayPalSDK/merchant-php-sdk 3.7.112 (lang=PHP;v=5.5.9-1ubuntu4.11;bit=8;os=Linux_3.16.0-43-generic;machine=x86_64;openssl=1.0.1f;curl=7.35.0)`

Comment: Thanks for letting us know. It is because you sent something to PayPal that it didn't like.

Answer (score 0):

Per the HTTP spec, any time HTTP 500 is returned, there is a bug in the system you are talking to.

For PayPal, such reports should be sent to [PayPal Merchant Support](https://www.paypal.com/mts). You should include any Debug-Id or Correlation-Id headers you find in the response, as they are used by support to look up what actually happened.